# How to review file names format with maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to find a way to review the files generated by running `mvn install`, my task basically is, review if the total characters in the name are correct, if at least one file name is not complying, I should make certain task.

Is this possible in a `pom` with `maven`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? could post those details here?

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi I have not tried nothing yet, I am searching because I dont know so much Maven, so I only wanted to know if there exists something that I could use or probably run a python script of nothing is existing.

Comment: Everything is possible and the options are endless. This question is too broad, and your requirements not precise enough.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Do you think the question is unclear? The basic task is to review the files generated by maven in a folder, these files should complain a rule in the name(length of the name), basically I have to make that comparison or review as you want to name it.

Comment: There is ambiguity in the question, from what I understand you would want to validate if the files generated by maven has specific characters and are of specific length. But you need to elaborate on the problem

Comment: 1. Which files? 2. What are the precise rules for file names to be valid/invalid? 3. When exactly (i.e. during which maven goal) is the check supposed to run? 4. What do you want to happen when files don't match? 5. Where/how is maven being run (OS, scheduler, build manager, automated/manual etc.)? 6. Show an example `pom.xml` for which you want to implement this.

Comment: Also would be helpful if you'd explain why maven even generates invalid filenames in the first place, considering you should have full control over what's happening in your build. It's possible you're having an XY-problem here.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Yes you are right, for example I have to check in the generated folder "target/samples" the names of all the files are at maximum 8 characters, if at least one of them is more than 8 I have to execute certain task(this still is not completely defined).

Comment: The files which are created by Maven follow an pattern. So the question is: What do you mean by `if the total characters in the name are correct, if at least one file name is not complying`? Example for this?

Comment: The rule for the file names that I have to follow is name->maximum 8 character, extension maximum 3 characters, for example "accxxtlg.bat", the idea is to check that all files inside the target folder fulfill this requirement, but I dont know if directly with Maven I can accomplish this or for example I need to use a python script.

Answer (score -1):

you can use dependency:analyze for that,

[https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html]

...

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>analyze</id>  <!-- notice the execution id "analyze" -->
        <goals>
            <goal>analyze</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: i already pre-empt his problem, it should not happen. this is the simplest way for him to check why he has those invalids. So rude the downvote. hehe

Comment: @Truth Sorry I dont so many details of Maven, could explain more your example? beacuse I dont see how this could help to my problem.

Comment: re "if at least one file name is not complying", what is the task that your writing? just curious

Comment: @Truth A downvote is not rude, it's a tool. Guessing OPs problem and then posting an answer to what you believe their problem is, is not helpful. Even if you are right, it won't be helpful to future readers who will find OPs question through search and don't have the problem you guessed was OP's. Instead of posting answers based on your guesswork (no matter how good that might be), ask OP for clarification and post an answer when the question has been edited for clarity. Once you have enough reputation you can comment on any post.

Comment: im just joking. i understand and got it. no worries. thanks.